# Message Temporary Redirect while executing python script

Tags: python, browser, http-headers, firewall

I am trying to use python script to send SMS through way2sms, The script used as below,

```
 #logging into the sms site
    url ='http://site24.way2sms.com/Login1.action?'
    data = 'username='+username+'&password='+passwd+'&Submit=Sign+in'

      # r = requests.get(url,allow_redirects=False) 
      # print r.url
 #For cookies

    cj= cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    p = opener.open("http://site24.way2sms.com/entry.action?id=ijrh&ec=0001&username=")
    #print p.read()
 #Adding header details
    opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120')]
    try:
        usock =opener.open(url, data)  
    except IOError as e:
        print "Message"
        print(e.reason)
    #return()

    print cj 
    jession_id =str(cj).split('~')[1].split(' ')[0]
    send_sms_url = 'http://site24.way2sms.com/smstoss.action?'
    send_sms_data = 'ssaction=ss&Token='+jession_id+'&mobile='+number+'&message='+message+'&msgLen=136'
    opener.addheaders=[('Referer', 'http://site25.way2sms.com/sendSMS?Token='+jession_id)]
    try:
        sms_sent_page = opener.open(send_sms_url,send_sms_data)
    except IOError:
        print "error"
        #return()

    print "success" 
    #return ()
```

The above code works good in my personal PC, however same code produce the temporary redirect warning in my office PC and sms not sent. Is this possible due to firewall/ any other browser configuration?

```
>>> execfile('test.py')
Enter text: Test SMS
Enter number: 81XXXXX
Message
**Temporary Redirect**
<CookieJar[<Cookie _sm_au_d=1 for .way2sms.com/>, <Cookie JSESSIONID=A05~F1387E4B5D9E33EC5EEBC6A698D430E6.w805 for site24.way2sms.com/>]>
success
>>>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In HTTP a Temporary Redirect (302) is not an error. It is very often used to bring the uses to a new page after a request has been processed. For example the login for redirects you to the page you came from.

Comment: Still no messages received, can you guess what might be cause.